# Как вызвать  родителя родительского класса?

Tags: ооп, php

```
class Loo{
    public static  $run=500;

}
class Boo extends Loo{
    public static  $run=200;

}
class Doo extends Boo{
    public static  $run=100;
    public static function method(){
        echo parent::parent::$run;
    }

}
Doo::method();
```

Как обратится к классу Loo и получить свойство $run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP:get_parent_class](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-parent-class.php)

Comment: Благодарен.

        $parent_class_name=get_parent_class();//Boo;

        echo $parent_class_name::$run;//200

        $grandparent=get_parent_class($parent_class_name);//Loo

        echo $grandparent::$run;

Answer (score 0):

```
class Loo{
    public static  $run=500;

}
class Boo extends Loo{
    public static  $run=200;

}
class Doo extends Boo{
    public static  $run=100;
    public static function method(){
        echo Loo::$run;
    }

}
Doo::method();
```

Comment: ну да...а если не извесно имя класса?